# simultaneous NSURLConnection by using unique delegates for each NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, foundationkit

I am try to handle multiple NSURLConnection at the same time by using a different delegate for each connection, for each NSURLConnection I create, I create a new delegate object, but for some reason only one NSURLConnection works at a time, any NSURLConnection I try to start whilst one is already running simply do not start, my delegate does not receive any of the method calls connection:didReceiveResponse:, connection:didReceiveData:, connectionDidFinishLoading: or connection:didFailWithError:. Am I misunderstanding something about how NSURLConnection and its delegate works. Reading other posts most people seem to have a single delegate for all there connections and then use some kind of dictionary to get the right object to handle the right connection. Is that the way you have to do it.

Comment: deleted my answer as @tony million pointed out it was incorrect. if you post some code will be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing should work fine. You can have multiple NSURLConnections in flight at once, each with its own delegate.

If you want to know why your case isn't working, you'll probably need to show your code in your question.

I hope that at least answers the general question.